# Como ler um arquivo JSON sem um servidor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um site estático simples com html, css e javascript hospedado no Dropbox, usando o javascript com o *framework* JQuery e tentando ler um arquivo JSON.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
});
```

Eu pesquisei sobre e percebi que isso é uma chamada AJAX para um recurso local através de uma solicitação HTTP, e que só seria possível se o site estivesse hospedado em um servidor. Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso? 
Porque isso acontece?

Comment: O site está hospedado no dropbox, então você tem um servidor. O JSON também está no dropbox, certo?

Comment: É que o dropbox é limitado apenas para scripts do lado do cliente e HTML, ele não é capaz de rodar coisas do lado do servidor, sim o arquivo JSON esta junto com o arquivo html, css e javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você já tem o JSON em um arquivo, no DropBox mesmo, pode usar o [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) conforme citou, o DropBox é o seu servidor de arquivos estáticos ;)

Para isto, basta passar a URL do seu JSON, digamos esteja nesta URL do DropBox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6061295/stack/json.json, então você poderia recuperar o conteúdo do JSON e suas propriedades assim:

```
$.getJSON("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6061295/stack/json.json", function(json) {
    console.log('id: ' + json.id);
    console.log('nome: ' + json.nome);
});
```

Agora, caso tenha o conteúdo do JSON na sua página HTML, poderá usar o [parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), ficando algo assim:

```
var json = '{"id":1, "nome": "Bruno"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log('id: ' + obj.id);
console.log('nome: ' + obj.nome);
```

Answer (score 5):

Dependendo do navegador que está usando, o acesso a recursos locais via AJAX será bloqueado mesmo que sua página também esteja armazenada no mesmo local.

Se a página fosse acessada através de uma URL, ainda que local, o problema não ocorreria. Uma solução simples é instalar um servidor local, como Apache ou Nginx. Assim você pode editar os arquivos e ver as mudanças imediatamente de forma confiável e segura.

Outra alternativa, caso esteja usando o Google Chrome, é executar o navegador com um [parâmetro que desabilita tal restrição](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/). Por exemplo:

```
/dir/chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Entretanto, eu não recomendaria esta solução a não ser para algum teste simples em situações específicas.