# JSON Javascript arquivo externo

Tags: javascript, json

Eu gostaria de carregar um arquivo externo json para a minha página html através do javascript.

Quando tentei, aconteceu o seguinte erro:
" Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https".

Ele acusa que eu não posso carregar arquivos usando o "File:///c:/", porém eu quero que meu arquivo esteja junto da pasta na minha máquina.

Uma solução que eu encontrei foi de colocar todo meu código e rodá-lo por exemplo pelo wampserver usando o localhost:80, porém não gostaria que tivesse que instalar o wamp ou algo do gênero.

É possivel eu carregar os dados do arquivo json sem ter que utilizar essa solução?

Comment: Seria bom adicionar na pergunta o código que está usando.

Answer (score 1):

***"Cross origin requests"*** é o termo chave aqui.

Com esse `file://c:` aí,  você está tentando carregar algo do sistema de arquivos do seu usuário. Se isso aí funcionasse, a sua página poderia acessar ativamente os arquivos do disco de quem quer que entrasse na sua página.

Isso seria mais ou menos equivalente a ter a senha do celular de todo mundo que entrasse em sua loja física.

Ponha o JSON na mesma pasta da sua aplicação WEB e carregue como carregaria um CSS ou Javascript qualquer. Assim o navegador sabe que você quer acessar algo que é seu e não do usuário.

Exemplo de como carregar um JSON assim. Tenha um arquivo Javascript chamado `foo.js`:

```
var meuJson = JSON.stringify({pessoa: { idade: 30, nome: "fulano" }});
function obterJson() { return meuJson; }
```

E para consumir na sua página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = obterJson();
</script>
```

Agora, se você quer acessar como se fosse o retorno JSON de um serviço (i.e.: usando *ajax*), aí não tem jeito. Você vai precisar de um servidor HTTP pra servir esse JSON mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar protocolo HTTP, não tem outra maneira, mas para não instalar o Wamp, você pode ter [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) instalado na sua maquina e instalar o pacote [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). isso irá lhe fornecer um protocolo HTTP sem utilizar o Wamp
Lembrando, que o http-server irá fazer algo similar ao wamp.

Comment: [Dá uma lida neste pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91865/como-ler-um-arquivo-json-sem-um-servidor)